# Live search in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a page that mimics real-time search - search results appear as the user types. The plugin below works well except I want to hide the results(ordered list) in the beginning and show each matching bullet as the user types.

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".commentlist li").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
   <fieldset>
       <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
   </fieldset>
</form>

<ol class="commentlist">
   <li>Comment #1</li>
   <li>Comment #2</li>
</ol>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the comments pre-loaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the comments are preloaded you can hide it initially in two ways.

1. Call $('.commentlist li').hide() on dom ready
2. Add a style `.commentlist li { display: none}`

Another minor tweak I would suggest is to Create a regex variable outside the loop statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        if(!filter){ // hide is no text
            $(".commentlist li").hide();
            return;
        }

        var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i"); // Create a regex variable outside the loop statement

        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".commentlist li").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) { // use the variable here
                $(this).hide();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = " + count);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t9aBg/1/)

You can obviously use animations like `fadeIn('slow')` and `fadeOut('slow')` instead of `show()` and `hide()` to animate the display of items, It in my opinion it is looking good as many items will be animating together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The display:none style works but when the text box is cleared I want to hide the comments again.

Comment: I get and error when I type in this line:
var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0, regex = new RegExp(filter, "i"));

Comment: This line:

var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0, regex = new RegExp(filter, "i"));

Answer (score 2):

In CSS add

```
.commentlist li{display:none;}
```

then in your js, the first if

```
if(filter == 0){$(this).fadeOut();}
```

then on last, instead of $(this).show() add $(this).fadeIn('slow')

```
$(this).fadeIn('slow');
```

Your UPDATED code here: http://tinyurl.com/a972s6t

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works, but I want to hide the comments (li's) when the textfield is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filter').keyup(function() {
        var f = $(this).val();
        var regex = new RegExp(f, 'gi');

        $('.commentlist li').hide()
            .each(function() {
                if($(this).html().match(regex)) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
    });
});
```

If you want fade animations:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filter').keyup(function() {
        var f = $(this).val();
        var regex = new RegExp(f, 'gi');

        $('.commentlist li').fadeOut()
            .each(function() {
                if($(this).html().match(regex)) {
                    $(this).stop().show();
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Demo of script in action: http://www.glow-raspberry.com/where-to-buy. Type "plaza" for example.