# search script in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Below link helped me to get search functionality in Jquery :

[Live search in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103358/live-search-in-jquery/15103493#15103493)

but I am facing problem below:

script mentioned in post above helping me for tree search but I am facing problem as this script fadeout child element of parent matching node.

problem statement:

- *parent one
- *child one
- *child two
- *parent two
- *child three

In above case if i will search for **"two"** then it will show parent one completely(parent node + child as well) and parent two but not the child of it i.e child three

I hope u get my problem any suggestion please?

Please see the script below I am using for the search functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#filter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    if(!filter){ // hide is no text
        $(".commentlist li").hide();
        return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i"); // Create a regex variable outside the loop statement

    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".commentlist li").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) { // use the variable here
            $(this).hide(); //**here I want to put condition that 
//checks for parent element and if its parent then 

//it should not fadeout the its child element** 
        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = " + count);
});
```

});

Comment: please add your code ..

Comment: I am using same script from referenced link. Going through the link will help you the get the code.

Comment: I have updated question now I hope this will help you guys to answer.

Comment: it works with no problems check it out http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/5uJZm/2/ check your html code it could be not compatible with the js code

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but if you will replace first and 4th "<li>" with "ul" then you will got to know my problem.

Comment: so you're talking about nested lists too ?

Comment: Yes you got it correct.

Comment: still working :/ http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/5uJZm/3/

Comment: check this if you don't want to use the proper li inside ul http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/5uJZm/4/

Comment: In my case I am using jquerytreeview and if you interchange last element with <ul> and <li> then you wont able to get parent two's child value on ui and in my case its required.

Comment: could you add your html code ?

Comment: there is no HTML it is a jquerytreeview it got loaded at run time with data based on user selection of item from left menu

Comment: I need to see the affected html at least

Comment: if u will see this http://jsfiddle.net/5uJZm/6/ and then u will try search for two then you won't be able to get third child but it should be there as I searched for two but it's child of parent two

Comment: it is working perfectly !.. I don't see the problem .. there are only 2 elements that contain "two" so it is correct

Comment: As in above case parent two is matching to search criteria then I need its child element should also visible while searching while in this case it's not working.

Comment: the child also appears in the search (when I search for "two" I get child two and parent two) .. if you're skeptical about the process you can add `$(this).children().show();` when you show `$(this)`

Comment: I need to show "child three" as it's child node of "parent two" and .children().show() is also not working for me.

Comment: OMG, child three is not a child of parent two, it is the child of commentlist .. let me rewrite that for you

Comment: give me test cases of the result you want. search:two => result : parent one, child two parent two ? you want to see the children of the element where the text was found or the parent ?

Comment: it is simple like in our fiddler example I have 2 parent nodes "parent one" and "parent two". now parent one has two child nodes child first and child second while parent two only have one child that is child three. now whenever I search for "two" the it should show result all nodes available in tree but if I will have parent three and having child as well it should not show up in result. Like here http://jsfiddle.net/5uJZm/7/ if you will search for "two" then "parent one" and "parent two" should be visible completely while parent three should not be there in result.

Comment: you're contradicting yourself, the logic is not consistent. if you want parent one to be visible with all of it's children on searching "two" it means that all the siblings of the element where the text was found and parents must be visible, and parent three has parent two as a sibling so it must be visible too. I'll stop pursuing this question as it is not clear and is extending too much.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience. I understand your frustration with it. If you still looking in to this then please see this http://jsfiddle.net/5uJZm/10/ probably it will help you to understand here if I search for "two" then I want to see first and second parent with all it's siblings.

Comment: like this link http://www.ztree.me/v3/demo.php#_113 here its highlight the text but I want it to fadeout other nodes.

Comment: it is working exactly like it, except in the case where you empty the textbox since you hide everything in that case where you should show them. the highlight is working exactly like the fiddle but with fading in/out instead. no siblings are highlighted nor parents. I'll stop here. there is no frustration since you didn't ask the question properly and the problem remains unclear. I advise you to delete the question and rewrite it in clear structure with test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting this line of code before .hide() fulfilled my requirement.

```
if ($(this).parent().is(":visible")) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
```